# Assigning a property value using CodeDOM

Tags: c#, codedom

I have code that generates this constructor:

```
public C001(string p8179_010, string p1131_020, string p3055_030, string p8178_040)
{
    this.@__E8179_010 = p8179_010;
    this.@__E1131_020 = p1131_020;
    this.@__E3055_030 = p3055_030;
    this.@__E8178_040 = p8178_040;
}
```

This is a subset of the code that creates the above code:

```
CodeTypeDeclaration classDecl = new CodeTypeDeclaration()
{
    Name = string.Format( "{0}", node.XPathSelectElement( "Code" ).Value ),
    IsClass = true
};

CodeConstructor constructor = new CodeConstructor();
constructor.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;

classDecl.Members.Add( constructor );

foreach ( var component in node.XPathSelectElements( "Components/Component" ) )
{
    string componentBackingField = string.Format( "__{0}_{1}", componentRef, component.XPathSelectElement( "Position" ).Value );
    string constructorParameterRef = string.Format( "p{0}_{1}", component.XPathSelectElement( "Element" ).Value, component.XPathSelectElement( "Position" ).Value );

    constructor.Parameters.Add( new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression( typeof( System.String ), constructorParameterRef ) );
    CodeFieldReferenceExpression paramRef = new CodeFieldReferenceExpression( new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), componentBackingField );
    constructor.Statements.Add( new CodeAssignStatement( paramRef, new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression( constructorParameterRef ) ) );
}
```

With my limited experience of CodeDOM, how do I amend this so that it does this:

```
public C001(string p8179_010, string p1131_020, string p3055_030, string p8178_040)
{
    this.@__E8179_010.Value = p8179_010;
    this.@__E1131_020.Value = p1131_020;
    this.@__E3055_030.Value = p3055_030;
    this.@__E8178_040.Value = p8178_040;
}
```

The difference is that I want to assign the parameter to the `Value` property of it's backing field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think like the compiler: with trees (specifically, syntax trees). When you write `this.@__E8179_010.Value`, the compiler sees something like:

[image]

Now, when you use `.` to access a field, it's represented as `CodeFieldReferenceExpression` and the two children in the tree are the two parameters in its constructor.

This means that the tree above can be written as:

```
new CodeFieldReferenceExpression( // second (upper) .
    new CodeFieldReferenceExpression( // first (lower) .
        new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), componentBackingField),
    "Value")
```

Or, if you don't want to bother with all this and like strings, just use [`CodeSnippetExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codesnippetexpression) (or possibly another `CodeSnippet*` type):

```
new CodeSnippetExpression(string.Format("this.{0}.Value", componentBackingField))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to figure it out, however I'm not certain it's the cleanest way to do it.

I changed this:

```
CodeFieldReferenceExpression paramRef =
    new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
        new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), componentBackingField );
```

to this:

```
CodeFieldReferenceExpression paramRef =
    new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(
        new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), string.format("{0}.Value", componentBackingField ));
```

and it worked!